# Got empty cursor on mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to mongodb and when I run `base.collection.find()` in the console it returns the expected but when running

```
collection.find({},(err,result)=>{
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```

it doesn't return anything. Also when trying

```
 let result = await collection.find({});
 console.log(result.toArray());
```

it logs an empty array.
The connection statement:

```
const {MongoClient, ObjectId} = require('mongodb');
const mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
const db = mongo.db('bd');
const collection = db.collection('users');
```

PD: As opposed to an empty find(), executing a findOne() works fine.

Comment: Are you sure the collection is having documents  and what is ```collection```?

Comment: Yes, the collection is having documents. In fact, inserting data to them with js works fine

Comment: Please include mongodb connection and import statement of ```collection```